# cassandra tool for snapshot management

Tags: cassandra

In *cassandra.yaml* file is specified:
***auto_snapshot: true***

After running for some time, issuing *nodetool listsnapshots* results in a long list of results, and the same keyspace has many lines.

The question is: does everyone write their own clean-up scripts or does there exist a general purpose one comprising parameters for, say, how many of the most recent to keep while deleting the others?

Answer (score 1):

There are no tools within Cassandra to manage snapshots aside from `nodetool clearsnapshot` [documented here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsClearSnapShot.html) for example. If you want to manage them then you'll need to script your own solution using your favourite language / methods.

**Some background**

The `auto_snapshot` setting (default `true`) means if you drop or truncate a table then it makes a snapshot of the data. If you have a lot of snapshots then you must be truncating / dropping quite often (do you need to do this?).

If you dont need the old data then you can turn this feature off. **Be careful though**; it goes without saying though that having this on as default has saved many a "whoops" moment!

Snapshots themselves are hard links so there isn't any duplication at the filesystem level, however if you never purge snapshots your data will grow over time (i.e you might have a sstable in a snapshot that has since been compacted away in your live data directories).